# how to parse an expression step by step in c# (preferably visitor pattern)

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I am new to c#. I have a question about parsing a string. If i have a file that contains dome lines such as `PC: SWITCH_A == ON` or a string like `PC: defined(SWITCH_B) && SWITCH_C == OFF`. All the operators(==, &&, defined) are string here and all the switch names(SWITCH_A) and their values are identifiers(OFF). How do i parse these kind of string? Do i first have to tokenize them split them by new lines or white spaces and then make an abstract syntax tree for parsing them? Also do i need to store all the identifiers in a dictionary first? I have no idea about parsing can anyone help? an tell me with an example how to do it what should be the methods and classes that should be included? Thanks.

Comment: If the lines are reasonably consistent, the simplest approach might be to read each line in, and then perform a string.Split(' '). This will return you an array of strings, which you can then parse accordingly.

Comment: See my SO answer on how to build a recursive-descent parser by hand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769 This is pretty easy for expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Yes. You have to tokenize them if the syntax that you are parsing is something custom and not a standard syntax where a compiler already exists for parsing the source.

You could take advantage of [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). They are there in the .NET Framework for building and evaluating dynamic languages.

To start parsing the syntax you have to have a grammar document that describes all the possible cases of the syntax in each line. After that, you can start parsing the lines and building your expression tree.

Parsing any source code typically goes a character at a time since each character might change the entire semantics of the piece that is being parsed.

So, i suggest you start with a grammar document for the syntax that you have and then start writing your parser.

**Make sure that there isn't anything already out there for the syntax you are trying to parse as these kind of projects tend to be error-prone and time consuming**

Now since your high-level grammar is

> Expression ::= Identifier | IntegerValue | BooleanExpression

`Identifier` and `IntegerValue` are constant literals in the source, so you need to start looking for a `BooleanExpression`.

To find a `BooleanExpression` you need to look for either `BooleanBinaryExpression`, `BooleanUnaryExpression`, `TrueExpression` or `FalseExpression`.

You can detect a `BooleanBinaryExpression` by look for the `&&` or `==` operators and then taking the left and right operands.

To detect a `BooleanUnaryExpression` you need to look for the word `defined` and then parse the identifier in the parantheses.

And so on...

Notice that your grammar supports recursion in the syntax, look at the definition of the `AndExpression` or `EqualsExpression`, they point back to `Expression`

> AndExpression ::= Expression '&&' Expression
>
> EqualsExpression ::= Expression '==' Expression

You got a bunch of methods in the [String Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) in the .NET Framework to assist you in detecting and parsing your grammar.

Another alternative is that you can look for a parser generator that targets c#. For example, see [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but i am not clear about where to start from that is my main concern for now

Comment: Start by finding a document that describes all the possible cases for syntax in each line in the case that you don't know. If you know, then you can start writing your parser.

Comment: I already have a grammer for this kind of a thing. i.e.
` *Expression ::= Identifier | IntegerValue | BooleanExpression
   * Identifier ::= <string>
   * IntegerValue ::= <integer>
    *BooleanExpression ::= BooleanBinaryExpression | BooleanUnaryExpression | TrueExpression | FalseExpression
     * BooleanBinaryExpression ::=  AndExpression | EqualsExpression
     * AndExpression ::= Expression '&&' Expression
     * EqualsExpression ::= Expression '==' Expression
     * BooleanUnaryExpression ::= DefinedExpression
     * DefinedExpression ::= 'defined' '(' Identifier ')'`

Comment: Thanks for putting effort and giving me some insights

Comment: @user5440565 You'll have problems with your current grammar as it seems to have indirect left recursion: `Expression -> BooleanExpression -> BooleanBinaryExpression -> AndExpression -> Expression`. Moreover, I strongly suggest to use a tool like ANTLR instead of implementing this by yourself, unless for academic purpose. You will save yourself a serious headache.

Comment: And now I see that Timothy more or less pointed that out already ;)

Comment: yes, this is academic and i hvae to do this, i cannot avoid it... thanks for the suggestion @PatriceGahide

Comment: ANTLR is overkill for expressions.  Yes, it will work.